# db2 -S is hanging on IBMi

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I can ssh into my IBMi and start qsh. If I type db2 with no parameters I get the standard help message:

```
db2
  USAGE: CMD [-v] [-S] [-s] [-t | -T<char> | -d] [-r RDBNAME [-u USERNAME -p PASSWORD] ] <"SQLSTMT" | -i | -f FILENAME DEFAULT_LIB>
```

However, if I run a query like `db2 -S "SELECT name FROM INFORMATON_SCHEMA.tables"` Nothing returns. It was working fine for the past couple of weeks. I can SELECT and UPDATE from php code just fine. However, I can't use the db2 commandline tool from qsh. What Should I do to troubleshoot?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that stdout has been redirected. Does echo work?

Comment: Could be PTFs too.  When you say 'nothing returns' what happens?  Normal completion with '0 RECORD(S) SELECTED.'?  An error message?  A hang?

Comment: @BuckCalabro it doesnt return. as in if I type exit afterwards, I don't go back from qsh to my ksh prompt in PASE. If I type qsh, and then exit before trying `db2 -S ""` then it does exit out of qsh back to the PASE ksh